Wrappers around write() and read() and a function to copy file permissions
Below follows wrappers around read() and write() that retry when interrupted by a signal (the case where the return value is -1 and errno has the value EINTR), two more wrappers around write() and read() that call write() and read() in a loop respectively until size bytes have been written/read, and a function to copy file permissions from one file to another.
Code:
io.h:
#ifndef IO_H
#define IO_H 1

#include <sys/types.h>

/** 
 * These functions return -1 on failure, or a non-negative integer otherwise. */

/** 
 * Version of read() that retries when interrupted by EINTR (possibly by a 
 * SIGWINCH). */
[[nodiscard, gnu::nonnull]] ssize_t io_read_eintr(int fd, void *buf, size_t size);

/**
 * Version of write() that retries when interrupted by EINTR (possibly 
 * by a SIGWINCH). */
[[nodiscard, gnu::nonnull]] ssize_t io_write_eintr(int fd, 
                                                   const void *buf, 
                                                   size_t size);

/**
 * Version of read() that retries when interrupted by EINTR (possibly by a 
 * SIGWINCH). */
[[nodiscard, gnu::nonnull]] ssize_t io_read_all(int fd, void *buf, size_t size);

/** 
 * A wrapper around io_write_eintr() that's called in a loop until size bytes 
 * have been written. */ 
[[nodiscard, gnu::nonnull]] ssize_t io_write_all(int fd, 
                                              const void *buf, 
                                              size_t size);

/** 
 * Copies src_fd's mode bits to dest_fd. */
[[nodiscard]] ssize_t io_copy_file_perms(int src_fd, int dest_fd);

#endif /* IO_H */

io.c:
#undef POSIX_C_SOURCE
#undef _XOPEN_SOURCE

#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200819L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700

#include "io.h"

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t io_read_eintr(int fd, void *buf, size_t size)
{
    ssize_t ret = 0;

    do {
        errno = 0;
        ret = read(fd, buf, size);
    } while (ret == -1 && errno == EINTR);

    return ret;
}

ssize_t io_write_eintr(int fd, const void *buf, size_t size)
{
    ssize_t ret = 0;

    do {
        errno = 0;
        ret = write(fd, buf, size);
    } while (ret == -1 && errno == EINTR);

    return ret;
}

ssize_t io_read_all(int fd, void *buf, size_t size)
{
    size_t rcount = 0;
    size_t bytes_left = size;
    ssize_t ret;

    for (ret = 0; rcount < size && ret != -1; rcount += (size_t) ret) {
        ret = io_read_eintr(fd, (char *) buf + rcount, bytes_left);
        bytes_left -= (size_t) ret;
    }

    return ret == -1 ? -1 : rcount;
}

ssize_t io_write_all(int fd, const void *buf, size_t size)
{
    size_t wcount = 0;
    size_t bytes_left = size;
    ssize_t ret;

    for (ret = 0; wcount < size && ret != -1; wcount += (size_t) ret) {
        ret = io_write_eintr(fd, (char *) buf + wcount, bytes_left);
        bytes_left -= (size_t) ret;
    }

    return ret == -1 ? -1 : wcount;
}

ssize_t io_copy_file_perms(int src_fd, int dest_fd)
{
    struct stat st;

    return fstat(src_fd, &st) != -1 && fchmod(dest_fd, st.st_mode) != -1 ? 0 : -1;
}

Review request:
Any bugs, missing error checking, et cetera.

Why does io_copy_file_perms() return a ssize_t when the return is really only doing a bool test?

@chux-ReinstateMonica It returned bool previously. Then I changed it to ssize_t for consistency with other functions in this file.


If the requested size exceeds the source file capacity, io_read_all will stuck in the infinite loop. Perhaps it shall break if ret == 0 (typically an end-of-file condition).

You may want to retry reads and writes on EAGAIN too. It is a transient error. ENOBUFS may also need to be addressed.

There is no need to set errno = 0 before calling read and write.



vnp, "There is no need to set errno = 0 before calling read and write."  deserves explanation.  I suppose it is unlikely that code will have errno = EINTR and then call  io_read_eintr(fd, buf, (size_t)-1).  What down-side do you see with errno = 0 inside io_xxxx_eintr()?

@vnp Is it possible to stuck in the theoretical situation where I just continue infinitely looping on EINTR?

@chux and Harith: If read() or write() returns -1, then it is specified that it sets errno.  If it returns a non-negative number, then this code doesn't read errno.  And we provide the same interface to our callers (in particular, it's unspecified whether errno is modified in the success case).

@TobySpeight Its more like "if error, -1 returns and errno set.  Otherwise it returns a number (no mention it is non-negative).  What would you expect io_read_eintr(fd, buf, (size_t)-1) to possibly return?

@chux: On success, the number of bytes read is returned - if you know a way for this to be negative, I'm interested to hear it.  I would expect that call to return some positive value (the size of the final read that completes it).  I guess you're referring to "if count is greater than SSIZE_MAX, the
result is implementation-defined" - that's a good point and it's almost certainly worth making sure that doesn't happen, given that this is supposed to be portable code!  I'd recommend reading chunks of SSIZE_MAX until the remaining amount is less than that.

@TobySpeight, aside,  *nix does not specify which is greater SIZE_MAX or SSIZE_MAX.  IIRC, they are not specified as the same bit-width.

@chux-ReinstateMonica What change would you suggest making to io_read_eintr(), or any other problematic function?

@Harith In *nix land, such functions return SSIZE_MAX. IMO, introducing yet another type SSIZE_MAX was not the best solution.

Sign-ness change
A picky compiler may complain about return ret == -1 ? -1 : rcount; with its implied type change from size_t to ssize_t as the sign-ness changes.
Use return ret == -1 ? -1 : (ssize_t) rcount; to quell the implied type sign-ness change warnings and make it explicit.
Minor: convoluted early exit of loop
io_read_all() and io_write_all() both have for loops that quit early when ret == -1.  Yet that loop stoppage involves an involved logic path.
Simplified alternate that has 2 return points.
As with such style issues, code to your group's coding guidelines.
ssize_t io_read_all_alt(int fd, void *buf, size_t size) {
  size_t rcount = 0;

  while (rcount < size) {
    ssize_t ret = io_read_eintr(fd, (char *) buf + rcount, size - rcount);
    if (ret == -1) {
      return -1;
    }
    rcount += (size_t) ret
  }

  return (ssize_t) rcount;
}

